# How do I use Git Flow to merge some (not all) feature branches already in Develop?

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, branching-and-merging

I am using Git Flow to organize my workflow. Sometimes we run into a problem where features have been merged into the develop branch and deployed to staging.

But then the client only wants some of the accepted features live. At this point we have a problem since I can't merge develop into master as it has features the client does not want in production yet.

To give an example, say I have 4 branches. `master` `develop` `feature-1` and `feature-2`. `master` is the current state of production. `develop` is the current state of staging and used as a starting point for new features.

Let's say a dev works on `feature-1` they're done, merge request back into `develop` the client accepts the new functionality and it's ready for further intergration testing. Now they start to work on `feature-2` same story as before.

Client comes in and says I need `feature-2` live but not `feature-1`. At this point we're in a pickle since `feature-2` already had the commits of `feature-1`.

What I came up with:

- Tell the client, tough luck `feature-1` also needs to be deployed (client not happy)
- Branch off `master` and cherry pick `feature-2` into it (eeew)
- Drop `develop` branch and use a `master` branch only for features that need to go to production. Problem here is harder intergration tests, features dependant on each other (clients sometimes take a long time to respond/test while development continues).

I'm looking for a way to change my workflow to allow some feature branches to be merged into master but not all. At the same time I don't want to handicap my devs by not merging features back into develop as most of the time development goes very quickly and features may depend on other features.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options here and you mentioned one of them:

1. Answering your question you can use [GitHub flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) or [GitLab flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html) using, for instance, only master to merge directly the features without develop branch, but IMHO (we are also using GitFlow) you need experimented developers and I do not know if the cost of learning a new workflow is worthwhile for you.
2. Even it is not exactly what you are asking, I would go for [Feature Flagging](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) which allows you to [deploy when you want, release when you're ready](https://launchdarkly.com/use-cases/). The new features are merged into `master` from `develop` and can be activated separately at runtime using flags. This way you could enable `feature-2` but not `feature-1` being both deployed. Launchdarkly has [open source SDKs](https://github.com/launchdarkly/featureflags) available althought you can also implement yourself.